# iOS Ad Hoc or Enterprise build doesn't install when I add GooglePlus.bundle

Tags: ios, installation, google-play-games, ad-hoc-distribution

I'm adding Google Play Games support to my game. The game builds and runs fine on my device with my developer certificates.

And, if I build the game for Ad Hoc distribution without the GooglePlus.bundle, it installs over-the-air.

However, if I include the bundle (from google-plus-ios-sdk-1.5.1) by dragging and dropping the bundle onto Xcode, or adding it through Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources, the build will not not install over-the-air. Like a plist / provisioning / certificate problem, the install proceeds to about 75% and then retreats and the popup appears: "Unable to Download App" "game could not be installed at this time." [done] [retry]

The first errors reported in the console
installd[60] : 0x2c3000 verify_signer_identity: MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo failed for /var/tmp/install_staging.hIQV4z/foo_extracted/Payload/tanks.app/tanks: 0xe8008017
installd[60] : 0x2c3000 do_preflight_verification: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.hIQV4z/foo_extracted/Payload/tanks.app

Again, the only change I'm making is this test is the addition of the bundle, and I'm stuck at the install. Are there additional steps I need to take to include a 3rd party bundle? It seems a little odd that bundle contains an executable - could the contents of the bundle prevent the install?